# Keep Twitter Bootstrap nav-collapse from expanding on some elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Using Bootstrap 2.3.2, I'm using `class="nav-collapse collapse"` to hide certain elements when the browser width shrinks. I'd like to keep some elements collapsed even when the user clicks the toggle button to expand the navigation. Is there some class I can apply to elements to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the responsive utility classes (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive)

For example, here the "About" link is hidden on phones and tablets:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about" class="hidden-tablet hidden-phone">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Bootply demo: http://bootply.com/87932

Comment: I'm already using those classes. My question is, when the user clicks the toggle button to expand the navigation, how can I selectively keep some elements collapsed?

Comment: So you have a dropdown in the collapse menu?

Comment: Nevermind, when you said "responsive utility classes" I thought you were referring to the `nav-collapse collapse`. I missed the `hidden-tablet hidden-phone` part. That will work. Thanks.